# How to show the long blob image from database in phpexcel?

Tags: phpexcel

I have a table store the data of image in long blob type, how to retrieve image show in phpexcel? My sample of code:

```
$order = "SELECT * FROM tblorder";

$tblorder = $conn->query($order);
$row_order = $tblorder->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$image =$row_order["image"];
$data = base64_encode($image);

$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('image');
$objDrawing->setDescription('image');
$objDrawing->getIndexedFilename($data);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A85');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($sheet->getActiveSheet());
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$pExcel = new PHPExcel();

$pExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$aSheet = $pExcel->getActiveSheet();

$aSheet->setTitle('Name');  

$data ='data://image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['Picture']);

$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($data);

$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();

$objDrawing->setName('Sample image');

$objDrawing->setDescription('Sample image');

$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);

$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);

$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);

$objDrawing->setHeight(150); 

$objDrawing->setCoordinates('I1');

$objDrawing->setWorksheet($aSheet);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.