Chart.js image with php excel
What im trying to do is convert chart.js to image with toDataURL then past it using ajax and using the url to set image path for php excel. I want to past the data without using any button and my php excel show nothing
script
        var canvas = document.getElementById('chart1');
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "?f=excel_customer",
            data: { imgData: imgData },
            success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            }
        });

php excel
 if(isset($_POST['imgData'])) {
   
$image= $_POST['imgData'];
         
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();    //create object for Worksheet drawing
$objDrawing->setName('chart');                     //set name to image
$objDrawing->setDescription('chart');              //set description to image
$signature = 'chart1';                             //Path to signature .jpg file
$objDrawing->setPath($image);
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(15);                        
$objDrawing->setOffsetY(15);                        
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('B2');        
$objDrawing->setWidth(90);                 
$objDrawing->setHeight(90);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());  //save image
 }

i dont know if it can be achieve or not. if not can someone suggest we another way do this but still using phpexcel

I don't know if phpexcel supports Data URIs for adding images; if not, you might need to do it this way, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47282406/1427878

What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem or a JS problem?

In my experience, setPath does not DIRECTLY accept base64 image string. So one of the ways is to apply the following trick:

save the chart1 data (base64 image string) into a temporarily file, e.g. xyz1234.png (where xyz1234 is a randomly generated string)
execute the statement $objDrawing->setPath($image); where $image is "xyz1234.png"
unlink (delete this temp file) after you have saved / generated the xlsx file
Please note that I intentionally disabled the chart.js animation -- otherwise the ajax submitted graphics may have all the plots at the animation "start" positions, which in that case will not be the chart you want) - you should know what I mean if you are well versed in chart.js

Note 1: For convenience, I have used the save_base64_image function as in the following post. to do (1) above, but of course you may use other similar functions if you wish
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153776/convert-base64-string-to-an-image-file
Note 2: Make sure the directory is writable (so as to save the temp file and generate the excel file)
Note 3: I trust that you will understand the reason that I am using a randomized string for the png filename, it is a good habit to do this, in particular if your system will be used by multiple users.
So the HTML is
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js">
</script>

<canvas id="chart1" style="max-width:300px;max-height:300px;"></canvas>

<script>
var xyValues = [
  {x:50, y:7},
  {x:60, y:8},
  {x:70, y:8},
  {x:80, y:9},
  {x:90, y:9},
  {x:100, y:9},
  {x:110, y:10},
  {x:120, y:11},
  {x:130, y:14},
  {x:140, y:14},
  {x:150, y:15}
];

new Chart("chart1", {
  type: "scatter",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,255)",
      data: xyValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
 animation: {
            duration: 0 // general animation time
        },
    legend: {display: false},
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{ticks: {min: 40, max:160}}],
      yAxes: [{ticks: {min: 6, max:16}}],
    }
  }
});
</script>


<script>
   var canvas = document.getElementById('chart1');
   var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1);
     //console.log(imgData);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "testso.php",
            data: { imgData: imgData },
            success: function(response) {
             //  document.getElementById('ajaxreturn').innerHTML=response;
             alert(response); 
            }
        });

</script>

and the php (testso.php) is
<?php

require_once('./PHPExcel1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
require_once('./PHPExcel1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

function save_base64_image($base64_image_string, $output_file_without_extension, $path_with_end_slash="" ) {
    //usage:  if( substr( $img_src, 0, 5 ) === "data:" ) {  $filename=save_base64_image($base64_image_string, $output_file_without_extentnion, getcwd() . "/application/assets/pins/$user_id/"); }      
    //
    //data is like:    data:image/png;base64,asdfasdfasdf
    $splited = explode(',', substr( $base64_image_string , 5 ) , 2);
    $mime=$splited[0];
    $data=$splited[1];

    $mime_split_without_base64=explode(';', $mime,2);
    $mime_split=explode('/', $mime_split_without_base64[0],2);
    if(count($mime_split)==2)
    {
        $extension=$mime_split[1];
        if($extension=='jpeg')$extension='jpg';
        //if($extension=='javascript')$extension='js';
        //if($extension=='text')$extension='txt';
        $output_file_with_extension=$output_file_without_extension.'.'.$extension;
    }
    file_put_contents( $path_with_end_slash . $output_file_with_extension, base64_decode($data) );
    return $output_file_with_extension;
}


$image = $_POST['imgData'];

$x1=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x2=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x3=   chr(rand(0,25)+97) ;
$x4=   chr(rand(0,9)+48) ;
$x5=   chr(rand(0,9)+48) ;

$path=$x1.$x2.$x3.$x4.$x5;





save_base64_image($image, $path, $path_with_end_slash="" );


$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("creater");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("test2");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("testSubject");

//$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
//$objWorkSheet2 = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();


$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('test');



$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();    //create object for Worksheet drawing
$objDrawing->setName('chart');                     //set name to image
$objDrawing->setDescription('chart');              //set description to image
$signature = 'chart1';                             //Path to signature .jpg file
$objDrawing->setPath($path.'.png');
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(15);                        
$objDrawing->setOffsetY(15);                        
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('B2');        
$objDrawing->setWidth(300);                 
$objDrawing->setHeight(300);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()); 




// for XLSX
//header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
//header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="DOWNLOAD_test'.$ry.'.xlsx"');
//header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');


$name = './newexcel.xlsx';
$objWriter->save($name);


unlink($path.'.png'); 

echo "Successful" ;

     ?>

Please find below the screen dumps of

HTML



excel file generated



i try to understand how it works and even try your code but i cannot make it

If you have set up the phpexcel properly and the directory is writable, it should work (I tested before I post this question). But if your system setup (e.g. phpexcel version) is different then you may need to amend your code to suit your needs

i know its already late to ask you this but i already understand how to do it. My new problem is 1) the url cannot be post if i dont open the page first where i made an ajax call, so the image save function not function. 2) i try to run both ajax call and the function on the same page and the problem is img tag cannot get the path because save function run at the same time.

HI, Did you post your new problems as a new question ? If I have time I will answer it by providing a suggested answer

hi, i already post new question just now.

Last time, when you generate you excel did you open your html page where you made ajax call or you directly opent testso.php?

Of course we need to open html page (or whatever front-end) -- it is a technical requirement because the canvas is generated by front-end javascript -- we cannot generate the chart/canvas (front-end object) by pure PHP (backend)
